# Javascript Easle.JS Canvas Game not showing images

Tags: javascript, canvas

Within this function

```
    /*!
 * 
 * UPDATE SCORE - This is the function that runs to add score
 * 
 */
function updateScore(num){
    if(num!=0 && !gameEnd){
        var colorz = binobject_arr[binplace_arr[num-1].id].srcs;

                if(num=1){
        window.alert('width 151   height 132   y 591   x '+ $.binHolder['bin1'].x +'   path '+ colorz);
    }
    else if(num=2){
        window.alert('width 151   height 132   y 591   x '+ $.binHolder['bin2'].x +'   path '+ colorz);
    }
    else if(num=3){
        window.alert('width 151   height 132   y 591   x '+ $.binHolder['bin3'].x +'   path '+ colorz);
    }

        var score = binobject_arr[binplace_arr[num-1].id].score;
        playerData[0].playerScore+=score;
        scoreTxt.text = resultScoreTxt.text = playerData[0].playerScore;

        var startX1=canvasH/100*30;
        scoreDisplayTxt.text = '+'+score+'PT';
        scoreDisplayTxt.x=canvasW/2;
        scoreDisplayTxt.y=startX1;
        scoreDisplayTxt.alpha=0;

        $(scoreDisplayTxt)
        .clearQueue()
        .stop()
        .animate({ alpha:1, y:startX1-(canvasH/100*6)}, 500 )
        .animate({ alpha:0}, 500 );
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
         resetGame();
    }, 50);
}
```

My window.alerts are giving me all the information needed to create a canvas image, but when I try using drawImage() with javascript and/or createjs.Bitmap with easle.js using these parameters I am not getting an image. I tried using preloading and waiting, but I am too much of a noob with Canvas to figure this out. This game was re purposed, so there is a lot going on, but I am trying to simply (so I though) switch the image from sauce to splash-sauce when the nugget lands in the bin.

Here is working code online:
http://robertson.partners/gm/

I am just trying to change the image from

robertson.partners/gm/assets/sauceYellow.png
to
robertson.partners/gm/assets/sauceYellow-splash.png

when the chicken lands in the bin, but locations of bins change. The X changes, but width, height, and y are always the same.